# 4 standard type of objects in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

This is a question that I saw in some interview.

Which are the 4 standard type of objects in JSF ?

Three are under the direct control of the JSF programmer, one is under the control of JSF – but under the indirect control of the JSF programmer.

Any idea which they are ?

Thanks 
JK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 scopes in JSF 2

- Request: The bean is created on every request-response action.
- View: The bean is alive while you keep in the same view in the navigator.
- Session: The bean is alive since its creation until the browser session expires (HTTP session).
- Application: The bean is alive since the application is deployed until the application is undeployed.

More info:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885/1065197)